# MUI React How to properly make a language dropdown

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, localization, jsx

I'm new to react with Typescript & MUI.
I'm working on a project that was originally built by someone else.

I need to modify an existing code and turn it into a `<Autocomplete />` dropdownlist

Can someone please help with this?
I'm not really sure how to do this and I have been working on this for hours.

So basiclly the code below is working fine, I just need to make some changes to wrap the Language list in a dropdown list.

Currently it is working more like a dropdown menu.

````
  const { borderRadius, locale, onChangeLocale } = useConfig();

  const theme = useTheme();
  const matchesXs = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('md'));

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const anchorRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState<string>(locale);

  const handleListItemClick = (
    event:
      | React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement>
      | React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>
      | undefined,
    lng: string
  ) => {
    setLanguage(lng);
    onChangeLocale(lng);
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setOpen(prevOpen => !prevOpen);
  };

  const handleClose = (event: MouseEvent | TouchEvent) => {
    if (anchorRef.current && anchorRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const prevOpen = useRef(open);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (prevOpen.current === true && open === false) {
      anchorRef.current.focus();
    }
    prevOpen.current = open;
  }, [open]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLanguage(locale);
  }, [locale]);

  return (
    <>
      <Box
        sx={{
          ml: 3,
          mr: 2,
          [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
            ml: 1,
          },
        }}
      >
        <Avatar
          variant="rounded"
          sx={{
            ...theme.typography.commonAvatar,
            ...theme.typography.mediumAvatar,
            border: '1px solid',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255, 0)',
            background: 'rgba(255,255,255, 0)',
            color: theme.palette.primary.dark,
            transition: 'all .2s ease-in-out',
            '&[aria-controls="menu-list-grow"],&:hover': {
              color: theme.palette.primary.main,
            },
          }}
          ref={anchorRef}
          aria-controls={open ? 'menu-list-grow' : undefined}
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={handleToggle}
          color="inherit"
        >
          {language !== 'en' && (
            <Typography
              variant="h2"
              color="inherit"
              sx={{ textTransform: 'uppercase', fontWeight: '500' }}
            >
              {language}
            </Typography>
          )}
          {language === 'en' && (
            <TranslateTwoToneIcon sx={{ fontSize: '2.2rem' }} />
          )}
        </Avatar>
      </Box>

      <Popper
        placement={matchesXs ? 'bottom-start' : 'bottom'}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorRef.current}
        role={undefined}
        transition
        disablePortal
        popperOptions={{
          modifiers: [
            {
              name: 'offset',
              options: {
                offset: [matchesXs ? 0 : 0, 20],
              },
            },
          ],
        }}
      >
        {({ TransitionProps }) => (
          <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
            <Transitions
              position={matchesXs ? 'top-left' : 'top'}
              in={open}
              {...TransitionProps}
            >
              <Paper elevation={16}>
                {open && (
                  <List
                    component="nav"
                    sx={{
                      width: '100%',
                      minWidth: 200,
                      maxWidth: 280,
                      bgcolor: theme.palette.background.paper,
                      borderRadius: `${borderRadius}px`,
                      [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
                        maxWidth: 250,
                      },
                    }}
                  >
                    <ListItemButton
                      selected={language === 'en'}
                      onClick={event => handleListItemClick(event, 'en')}
                    >
                      <ListItemText
                        primary={
                          <Grid container>
                            <Typography color="textPrimary">English</Typography>
                            <Typography
                              variant="caption"
                              color="textSecondary"
                              sx={{ ml: '8px' }}
                            >
                              (UK)
                            </Typography>
                          </Grid>
                        }
                      />
                    </ListItemButton>

                    <ListItemButton
                      selected={language === 'sv'}
                      onClick={event => handleListItemClick(event, 'sv')}
                    >
                      <ListItemText
                        primary={
                          <Grid container>
                            <Typography color="textPrimary">Svenska</Typography>
                            <Typography
                              variant="caption"
                              color="textSecondary"
                              sx={{ ml: '8px' }}
                            >
                              (SE)
                            </Typography>
                          </Grid>
                        }
                      />
                    </ListItemButton>
                  </List>
                )}
              </Paper>
            </Transitions>
          </ClickAwayListener>
        )}
      </Popper>
    </>
  );
};

export default LocalizationSection;```
````

Comment: "So basically the code below is working fine". Where is the problem then? What have you done and where are you struggling at?